# method overloading with different signature and return type

Tags: java, oop, overloading

Method overloading is possible **only if** the overloaded methods have different signatures.
It cannot be possible if the signature is same and only the return type is different.

Quote from Java Docs:

> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

But what is the problem with having overloaded methods with different signatures and different return type simultaneously? Why does that give an error?

Comment: What does the JLS have to say on this?

Comment: Please show the code that gives you an error.

Comment: Your error is -- you're not returning anything!!! Your `int a(...)` method is declared to return an int and you return nothing. Lesson: read the error message.

Answer (score 3):

This should be OK per the [JLS 8.4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> ...There is no required relationship between the return types or between the throws clauses of two methods with the same name, unless their signatures are override-equivalent.

e.g., this compiles and runs fine:

```
public class Test {
   void move(int x, int y) {
      System.out.println("inside void move(int x, int y)");
   }

   int move(double x, double y) {
      System.out.println("inside int move(double x, double y)");
      return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.move(0, 0);
      test.move(0.0, 0.0);
   }
}
```

---

Regarding your posted code, your error is -- you're not returning anything! Your `int a(...)` method is declared to return an int and you return nothing. Lesson: read the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code has nothing to do with method overloading.

Your third method should return an int. It has an empty body, so it's not returning anything. If you change it to

```
int a(double q){
    return 0;
}
```

the error will go away